# how to specify a startup script in dataflow job for Java that will execute on each dataflow VM worker

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a requirement to modify ~/.ssh/authorized_keys to add custom public keys for login. I found this article which is for python job.
https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/python-pipeline-dependencies/

How can we do same for Java dataflow job.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a custom container, potentially with a custom entrypoint.

See:
https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/using-custom-containers

There is also https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/harness/JvmInitializer.java , that may potentially help here, but it was written for a different purpose.